# How to covert multiple list with different number of elements into a csv file

Tags: python

I have been attempting to convert multiple lists with different lengths into a CSV file using pandas using

```
list_1 = [0,1,2]
list_2 = [0,7]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records({"col1": list_1, "col2": list_2)
df.to_csv("data.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

however, this piece of code requires the same number of elements in each list and I have been unable to find a piece of code which allows this

Comment: You can convert `list_1` and `list_2` to `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do with the missing value (difference length means there are missing values), this code below will fill the missing values with `NaN` at the end of lists which have length less than max length:

```
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [0,1,2]
list_2 = [0,7]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"col1": list_1, "col2": list_2}, orient='index').transpose()
df.to_csv("data.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for